# how to limit the length of numeric value in laravel 10?

Tags: laravel, validation, laravel-10

is this the correct way to validate a numeric value where the field is tinyint(4)?

here's the command I'm using right now

```
['required', 'numeric', 'max:4']
```

Comment: I'd assume something like `max:9999` if you want to limit to 4 digits

Answer (score 3):

According to the [Laravel documnnetation](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/validation#rule-max-digits) you can use `max_digits`:

```
['required', 'numeric', 'max_digits:4']
```